# SilverStripe GD Image and Text

Tags: php, image, text, gd, silverstripe

I'm looking for a solution to have this kind of functionality to work on silverstripe:

http://papermashup.com/demos/php-gd-image-and-text/

Basically I would like to make an object on the back (page) with uploadable fonts and base image and then on the front end (for any user) I would like to have a form with font chooser (from fonts I've uploaded for this particular page) - finally it will generate the image with some text.

I can't find any solution for SilverStripe.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds rather like you're asking for help with a particular solution, and not with a specific issue that you're having.

What have you tried so far? Did you check https://addons.silverstripe.org? What did you find?

What you're asking is totally possible, and off the top of my head requires a a custom subclass of GDBackend which will interact with GD directly, a custom Controller comprising a single public method who's logic calls your custom GD logic to generate the image, and some basic jQuery+AJAX to POST the form-field values into your controller.

Comment: I thought I could base that on this: 

http://www.adisurya.net/blog/2012/02/watermark-image-with-png-or-text-in-silverstripe/ 

So that's basically like that watermark but in different form. 

I know how to make that page on the back and form as well but how to invert it - so user can generate an image?

Comment: A user can generate an image by uploading one via an UploadField embedded in a form (These can be used in the frontend too, not just the CMS). But I get the feeling you really mean "generate" vs "upload"..?

Comment: I need in fact a solution where I can have a lot of base object (for example mugs, t-shirts, etc.) and the front-end user will be able to pick one and then add text to it - at the end it will generate an image with base images and text embeded on it. 

So I thought it would be good to have each object (mug, t-shirt, etc.) as a page (this will be managed, image uploaded and fonts - via backend) and then to each page (or each of this type of Page) would have a form with which user can add text and generate his own.  

Any idea how can I get it to work?

Comment: @MaciejSwierczewski This is way to complicated and specific to be a good candidate for a Stackoverflow question. If you have implemented most of your logic, but struggle with a detail, ask about that thing. Otherwise you'd be better off hiring somebody to implement what you need.